# How to show a long list of results that are retrieved from webservices to users?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, struts2

I am receiving a large number of items from different webservices and need to show them to user (based on ascending order of their prices).

**Take SkyScanner as an example** of this requirement, user selects a specific flight and the website make request to different web services to receive the results.

The question is that, users have access to different filters such as 'show more' and 'sort by price' and I am wondering after retrieving the results from all webservices and sorting the results where I should keep the results? **(Show more is similar to pagination, by clicking on 'show more' I need to move to the next page)**

'Show more' : at first I need to show first five results and if show more is clicked show more results.
'Sort by price" : this option sort the results based on their price.

**Back-end**

```
 public String retrieveResultsFromWebservices(){
    results = new ArrayList();
    results = wb1();
    results = wb2();
    results = wb3();
    results = wb4();
    results = wb5(); 
    return "results";
 }
```

**Front-end**

```
        .....
        <tr>results.name</td><td>results.price</td></tr>
      </c:forEach>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

**More details**

Imagine user is looking for a list of products of all shops of the city, so I send request to the webservice of all shops to receive the list of their products. Then user is able to sort them based on their price, and also able to view the first five items, before clicking on show more to see the second five items.

Comment: retrieve all is never a good idea from design perspective as you are loading lots of data that will never be seen/used by user. On demand data will be a good approach, possibly via ajax.

Comment: @akshayb I forgot to include that at first I need to sort the results based on their prices (ascending) and if user click on show more I show the rest.

Comment: @Jack That should be done via SQL (or whatever webservice)

Comment: @ScaryWombat does that mean I should retrieve the results from webservices, insert them into db and retrieve them from there?

Comment: assuming its you who is sorting results (randomly ordered) coming from a remote server, I don't think there could be any possibility to sort without loading all the data. Doesn't web-service api you are using provide this facility (sort) ? All you can do is limit results to avoid load. But again, that won't provide good results from user perspective. Why don't you ask user to provide sort criteria he/she wants before loading ? probably that way, you can reduce unnecessary data transfer. btw how much is it in kbs ? you need not worry about few hundred kilo bytes.

Comment: or if possible, you can get count in one query and then use LIMIT (if api allows) to paginate.

Comment: @jack No, I was thinking along the same line as akshayb.  This is something that the back-end webservice should provide

Comment: Thanks guys, I was thinking of caching the result, because I can send a limited number of requests to each webservice, imagine a few of the users try sorting them for few times then I need to send multiple requests to the webservices. Regarding the size, I am not sure how to weigh the amount of results array. any comments?

Comment: In addition, I would appreciate it if you could vote up the question to attract more viewer.

Comment: how about jquery datatables?  http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: IS or IS NOT the webservice you call able to sort ? Does it publish a method signature with a parameter to specify the order for the returned results ? Like `findAll(String orderByThisColumn)` ? And especially, can you (or others in your or other groups) change the webservices, or they're 3rd party and you can only change your code, not their ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I am able to sort the results in some of the web services not all BUT as I said the problem is that I would like to limit the number of times I am sending requests to the web services as I am not authorized to send unlimited number of requests everyday. I do not get what you mean by findAll. I just send customized requests to the web services and receive the results. I just have access and authorization to change my own code not the other side's one, take skyscanner website as an example that sends request to many different web services and return the results to user.

Comment: IF you can alter the webservices code, you can include both sort (wherever not already implemented) *and pagination*. That way, if you ask for 10 results starting from page3 (30th result) on the overall records ordered by fieldX, calling a webservice each time is not a problem anymore (it will load 10 records instead of 100000 per request). THEN you can improve your application to prevent, for example, more than one request every 3 seconds, by temporary disabling the search / order button, and checking it server side too.

Comment: @AndreaLigios as I said I can not sort the results, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: It **REALLY** depends on your usecase. Does the data change a lot ? Do you need to reflect the changes immediately ? Can you cache it once a day (eg. in the night with a batch), or once an hour ? Are you writing a Crawler ? Do you expect 10 or 10.000 users ? I didn't know SkyScanner, I've opened it now, but a service like that can't be cached; if I need to book for a flight, the thing must be immediately reflected to every other user of the site... I'm afraid you need to figure out something *smart* here, it could be not naive...

Comment: @AndreaLigios thanks for your comment, I am implementing a similar website to skyscanner, it needs to retrieve results from different systems and show them to users. You are right, the results should be live. The question is that is this a correct approach to retrieve the results and load them all on web browser and use the javascript and other languages to filter them? is not it possible to keep them somewhere and read them from server partially rather than loading them all on browser?